# Problem on angles

Tags: geometry

**In triangle ABC, AB = AC and angle BAC = 20. A point D lies on the side AB and AD = BC. Find angle BCD?**

My construction involved drawing a line parallel to BC intersecting AC at E. However, I am still unable to link this to the known angles!

Hint please!

Comment: HINT: Construct an isosceles triangle $ADE$ with $\angle AED=20^\circ$

Comment: A further hint please! How do we solve this without using trigonometry...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Let $\angle BCD=\theta$

If you apply sine rule in the $\Delta ADC$ you'll get :

$$\frac{AD}{\sin(80^\circ-\theta)}=\frac{DC}{\sin20^\circ}$$

And doing the same in the $\Delta BDC$ you'll get:

$$\frac{BC}{\sin(100^\circ-\theta)}=\frac{DC}{\sin80^\circ}$$

Dividing these two relations you get:

$$\frac{\sin(100^\circ-\theta)}{\sin(80^\circ-\theta)}=\frac{\sin80^\circ}{\sin20^\circ}$$

**EDIT**:I had time so I decided to add how I got the value of $\theta=70^\circ$

$$\sin20^\circ\sin(100^\circ-\theta)=\sin80^\circ\sin(80^\circ-\theta)$$

$$\sin20^\circ\sin(80^\circ+\theta)=\sin80^\circ\sin(80^\circ-\theta)$$

$$\sin20^\circ\sin80^\circ\cos\theta+\sin20^\circ\cos80^\circ\sin\theta=\sin^280^\circ\cos\theta-\sin80^\circ\cos80^\circ\sin\theta$$
Rearranging,

$$\tan\theta=\tan80^\circ{\sin80^\circ-\sin20^\circ \over \sin80^\circ+\sin20^\circ}$$
$$\tan\theta=\tan80^\circ{\cos50^\circ \sin30^\circ \over \sin50^\circ \cos30^\circ }$$
$$\tan\theta=\tan80^\circ\tan40^\circ\tan30^\circ$$
$$\tan\theta={\tan80^\circ\tan40^\circ\tan30^\circ\tan20^\circ\over \tan20^\circ}$$
Now just apply this identity with $x=20^\circ$:
$$\tan x\tan(60^\circ-x)\tan(60^\circ+x)=tan3x$$
$$\tan\theta={1\over \tan20^\circ}=\tan70^\circ$$

Comment: Was thinking of a non-trigonometric solution using the hint above!